# jQuery loader - Loading from 0 - 100 and do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

I have a script that loads an advertisement:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// on document load:
$(function() {
   // set "waiting" message:
   $("#loadingStatus").html("Waiting for your advertisements to load...");

   // on iframe load:
   $('#iFrame').load(function() {
       // set "done waiting" message:
       $("#loadingStatus").html($("#isDone").html());
   });
});
</script>
```

What I wish to do, is that to create/get a loading bar/loading text that will appear, whenever iframe is done loading. After the loading bar is done loading, it should submit a PHP page.

Comment: What does *it should submit a PHP page* mean?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question...and your title...

Comment: Mockup diagrams will help here. This problem statement is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function() {
   // set "waiting" message:
   $("#loadingStatus").html("Waiting for your advertisements to load...");

   // on iframe load:
   $('#iFrame').load(function() {

       $("#loadingStatus").html($("#isDone").html());

       var dataToSubmit = {};
       $.post({
         url: "phpPage.php",
         data: dataToSubmit,
         success: function(){}
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: But I wish to use the post function to a php page, WHEN the bar is done loading.

Comment: Pass the php page which you want to submit in the url param it will submit to it and only when the iframe is loaded.

Comment: Not when the iframe is loaded. It should run when the loading bar is loaded. 
It looks like this:
 - iFrame loads.
 - Loading bar loads to 100%.
 - php page is run.

Comment: I am also looking for someone that can help me get a useful loading bar.